# How to split data and reload while scrolling in UITableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I have 100 records to load in UITableview, initially I just wanted to reload first 25 records,and while we scrolling the tableview after 25 records, table wants to reload next 25 records like that i want to do for all records in ios.How can i do this? anybody help me?

Comment: Where are the records coming from? If you have all of the data locally then there is no reason at all to do this.

Comment: UITableView will create cell instance for only the visible cells remaining cell will be dequeued once scrolled up or down.So there no need to do as like u want.

Answer (score 1):

Declare   `row_count` as int. In `viewDidLoad` set `row_count = 25;` and then `numberOfRowsInSection` replace `return [table_array count];` by  `return row_count;` Then add my method with my  code in `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return row_count;
    } 

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
        CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;  
        CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
        CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
        UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
        float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
        float h = size.height;
            float reload_distance = 10;
        if(y > h + reload_distance) {
            row_count = (row_count + 25 > [table_array count])?[table_array count]:row_count + 25;        
            [Yourtable reloadData];
        }
    }
```

Set like this.. It will load your data as you want